# How do you represent the equivalent of java's MyType<? extends MyConstraint> in typescript without using "any"?

Tags: java, typescript

In Java I could write something like `List<MyClass<? extends MyConstraint>>` to express *"a list of instances of MyClass instanciated with various types for T, all extending MyConstraint"*.

It's not the same thing as `List<MyClass<MyConstraint>>`, because `A` inheriting `MyConstraint` doesn't make `MyClass<A>` assignable to `MyClass<MyConstraint>`

I think typescript should be expressive enough to express that, but I can't find how to do it... Did I miss something here ?

Oh and our project uses the `no-explicit-any` eslint rule. So it this situation a valid usecase for `List<MyClass<any>>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivilent in Typescript is actually very similar to what you referenced with Java.

```js
type Foo<T extends MyConstraint> = Array<MyClass<T>>;
```

This would create an array type where the instances of `MyClass` have their parameterized generic argument constrained to anything that is a sub-type of `MyConstraint` just as you had done with Java.

This can come in different flavors depending on what you're doing (creating a type, defining a generic class, defining a generic function, etc) but the basic syntax is `<T extends SomeConstraint>`.

Here's the relevant Typescript docs talking about generic constraints which covers all the details:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints